# update the database dataset without deleting it and creating a new one

Tags: database, vb.net

i'm developing a program on VB.net and it needs a database. My problem is that the client is all the time changing the structure of the database, adding some fields or changing the type of the data because after thinking a bit more he thinks is better.

After the database change, i have to erase the dataset and recreate again, so all the code that needs it, or all the Datagrids makes error (sometimes all the for is deleted).

Example code: (this creates a list of buttons)

```
Private Sub List_Products_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load       

    Me.ProductosTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Bbdd_DataSet.productos)
    Dim code As String 
    Dim contador As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To Bbdd_DataSet.productos.Count - 1
        code = Bbdd_DataSet.productos(i).numero

        If InStr(code, "2") = 1 Then
            lst_prod.Items.Add(codigo)
            lst_precios.Items.Add(Bbdd_DataSet.productos(i).precio)
            btns = New System.Windows.Forms.Button
            btns.Left = 75
            btns.Width = 125
            btns.Height = 100
            btns.Font = New Drawing.Font("Times New Roman", 12, FontStyle.Regular)
            If code = 0 Then
                btns.Top = botones.Height * contador
            Else
               btns.Top = (botones.Height + 10) * contador
            End If

            btns.Text = Bbdd_DataSet.productos(i).nombre
            btns.Name = codigo

            AddHandler btns.Click, AddressOf add
            Controls.Add(btns)
            contador = contador + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

On all the code that apear "Bbdd_DataSet" makes error becasue the DataSet have beed deleted.

Is there any way to update the DataSet without deleting it and creating a new one? Becasue is a waste of time create the code again.

Thanks all.

Comment: Could you give an example wit code? @Fernando

Comment: What will happen if your client changes the schema after your application is delivered?

Comment: the problem is not the code, if i change the structure of the database, those changes are nor update on the Dataset, so i have to erase it, and create it again. doing that is when errors apear. i ask for other way to update the Dataset. i cant imagin witch code can explain this.

Comment: @Fernando I mean I want to see a piece of your code.

Comment: @amrswalha you have some code, all part of the code that have Bbdd_DataSet makes error. I need to update the dataSet wothout deleting it.

Comment: @Jodrell i told him that the program dont work if he do that. But the problem is Update the DataSet wothout deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: @Fernando I think better for you to find a new way to add the data to the data grid. This way seems way too complicated. I think it's better for you to get the data in the data set then add columns to the grid progmratically based on the columns inside the dataset. this way is much better and easier than the way above.

Comment: @amrswalha its easy to add colums on the datagrid. the problem is that if i add a colum on the Database, the Dataset is not updated, so i cant add that new colum to the grid because that colums is not on the Dataset.

Comment: @Fernando okay so that's the problem. Okay you see the ProductosTableAdapter.Fill is it a SqlDataAdapter? if so do you take the data from an stored procedure? you need to set the sql statement to select * to get all the columns.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40945/discussion-between-amrswalha-and-fernando)